# Compress JSON payload to GZIP for loading into BigQuery from Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, gzip

I'm working on a project to automate data pulls from an API and inserting them into Google BigQuery, and I've run into a few challenges regarding data uploads to Google Cloud Bucket's due to a 100mb daily data cap. I'm wondering if anyone has found a way to GZIP data in Google Apps Script prior to sending it off to BigQuery (in the correct format)?

Here is what I have currently:

```
function compress_string() {
// Import Compression Library
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pieroxy/lz-string/master/libs/lz-string.js').getContentText());

// Compress Sample JSON Data
var string = "{"kind": "person", "fullName": "John Doe", "age": 22, "gender": "Male"}";
Logger.log("Size of sample is: " + string.length);
var compressed = LZString.compress(string);
Logger.log("Size of compressed sample is: " + compressed.length);

// Save Compressed JSON to GCB
}
```

The only problem with this is that it seems like this is not an acceptable GZIP algorithm for BigQuery. I am able to save the .gz file but I get an error when attempting to import that file.

```
Errors:
file-00000000: Failed to parse JSON: Unexpected token; Parser terminated before end of string (error code: invalid)
```

Side note: When I export data from BigQuery in a .gz format, I am able to import it into a new table just fine. I notice that the icon's are different when they are both in Google drive as well:
[GZIP_File_Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRLcL.png)

Any help/guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!